# how to hide a user control according to the query string in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to hide a user control according to the query string in aspx page using script.
I have tried this one but it is not working.

```
<%# (Request.QueryString["catl1"] == "ask_the_expert") ? ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = false : ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = true%>
<uc3:ucTalkToExpert ID="ucTalkToExpert1" runat="server" />
```

It is not still hiding ucTalkToExpert1 user control even when the queryString is ask_the_expert.

I can't touch the backend code.

UPDATE

I don't have the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack the aspx page by putting an `if` statement around it.

```
<% if (Request.QueryString["catl1"] != "ask_the_expert") { %>
<uc3:ucTalkToExpert ID="ucTalkToExpert1" runat="server" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: You should use this technique sparingly, it prevents the control from rendering regardless of its `Visible` property value.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in code behind would be much cleaner.

```
if(Request.QueryString["catl1"] == "ask_the_expert")
     ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = false;
else
     ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = true;
```

OR, if you do not have code behind

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Request.QueryString["catl1"] == "ask_the_expert")
     ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = false;
   else
     ucTalkToExpert1.Visible = true;

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! if the page_load is there in the backend code, will it be still OK ?

Answer (score 1):

ASPX:

```
<uc1:ucTalkToExpert1 ID="ucTalkToExpert11" runat="server" Visible=<%# Request.QueryString["catl1"] == "ask_the_expert" ? false : true %>  />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<uc3:ucTalkToExpert ID="ucTalkToExpert1" runat="server" />
```

to

```
<uc3:ucTalkToExpert Visible="false" ID="ucTalkToExpert1" runat="server" />
```